# Element (icon button) not showing up with the correct width

Tags: html, css, polymer, material-design

I'm working with a icon button which is placed in a scroll header panel. Even though I explicitly added a rule for the width, it is still showing up as 100% width:

[image]

What is so strange is that if I move the button and place it into the content of the page, the size is right again. I just can't figure out what is messing up the width.

Relevant code:

```
<paper-drawer-panel transition>
        <div drawer></div>
        <paper-scroll-header-panel class="flex" condenses main>
            <paper-toolbar class="tall">
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" title="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                <div class="bottom title">Title</div>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        ...
```

Comment: Consider changing inline-block to block

Comment: @xrisk - Tried that, same result.

Comment: Could you tell us the styles of the parent?

Comment: Try putting the width into element.style

Comment: @xrisk - I actually didn't apply any custom style to the toolbar. They are straight from the paper elements.

Comment: It seems to me that a relational style is causing it — hence the problem disappears when you move it out. Since inline styles have the highest cascade order, defining the width inline should fix it. (I think).

Comment: I have no experience with paper

Comment: Even adding something like `style="width: 24px` doesn't fix it. Its parent does have some flexbox properties and it may have something to do with that.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I have no idea what flex boxes are.

Comment: Try adding a `span` with `flex:1;` after the button.

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal Sorry for that late response, but that just cut the width into half.